# Is it possible to create a hyperlink which will activate a spreadsheet and run a macro?

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I currently generate email queries from an excel/vba interface. These emails are to query a specific transaction.

I would like to embed a hyperlink into these emails which would allow the user to navigate to the spreadsheet and trigger a macro with a parameter.

EG: 
    `<a href="excel:transcheck.xlsm ViewTrans(transID=1234)>investigate</a>`

The result of clicking this link should be that Excel is activated, the spreadsheet is opened, the ViewTrans subroutine within the macro is called with the paramater TransID = 1234.

All google search results relate to embedding hyperlinks WITHIN excel, which is of course very straightforward. My question is about how to create an EXTERNAL hyperlink, that can be sent over email. Thanks in advance for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.

It will not be working as you want. Even if you find a way (I don't think so) the Macro security settings can be set to not run macros on end user machines.

I'd suggest looking for another options.